# Math.Round with progressbar

Tags: vb.net, math, rounding

I use this code to list files from directory :

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        rslts = New List(Of String)
        foo(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.ApplicationData))
        ListBox1.Items.Clear()
        ListBox1.Items.AddRange(rslts.ToArray)
    End Sub

    Dim rslts As List(Of String)

    Private Sub foo(ByVal aDir As String)
        Try

            Dim di As New IO.DirectoryInfo(aDir)
            Dim aryFiles() As IO.FileInfo = di.GetFiles("*.*")
            Dim aryDirs() As IO.DirectoryInfo = di.GetDirectories()

            For Each fi As IO.FileInfo In aryFiles
                rslts.Add(fi.FullName)
            Next

            For Each d As IO.DirectoryInfo In aryDirs
                foo(d.FullName)
            Next

        Catch ex As Exception

        End Try

    End Sub
```

I wan't to use `Math.Round()` with this so I can add increment to progressbar while loading files.I know I need to use timer,but I am not familiar with `Math.Round()`

So basically,I wan't real progressbar while loading files into listbox.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to perform the increment calculations, `ProgressBar` takes care of everything. How to use it (`ProgressBar1`) with your code:

```
Private Sub foo(ByVal aDir As String)

    Try
        Dim di As New IO.DirectoryInfo(aDir)
        Dim aryFiles() As IO.FileInfo = di.GetFiles("*.*")
        Dim aryDirs() As IO.DirectoryInfo = di.GetDirectories()

        With ProgressBar1
            .Minimum = 0
            .Maximum = aryFiles.Count + aryDirs.Count
            .Value = 0
            .Step = 1
        End With

        For Each fi As IO.FileInfo In aryFiles
            rslts.Add(fi.FullName)
            ProgressBar1.PerformStep()
        Next

        For Each d As IO.DirectoryInfo In aryDirs
            foo(d.FullName)
            ProgressBar1.PerformStep()
        Next

    Catch ex As Exception

    End Try

End Sub
```

Comment: Should i use it in timer sub or foo sub?If i use it in foo sub it just fills the progressbar.

Comment: @Jedi how are you planning to use the timer? Within the loops? The timer is only called after the loop is over and thus just once per loop. My code is expected to be included in your code (in `foo`).

Comment: @Jedi - You probably need to just call ProgressBar1.Update() after you call PerformStep to get the progress bar to reflect its new value.

Comment: @ChrisDunaway If you test this code, you would see that it works fine. And if you take a look at the MSDN sample code (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.progressbar.aspx) you would also see that there is no reference to this call. In general, I only use this kind of methods (.Update(), .Refresh()) when have confirmed that the given control actually needs them (not the case with ProgressBar) or when performing many "variations" on the GUI which might advise being in the safest-side. But, in general, I intend to avoid this and never recommend what is not required.

Comment: @varocarbas - Admittedly, I did not test the code as presented.  Based on `Jedi's` first comment, it seemed like the UI was not getting updated until the For loops ended, so I suggested the Refresh call.  As you know, the UI often doesn't get updated when the code is running in tight loops because the message queue doesn't get processed.  In the case of the PerformStep method, internally the method calls SendMessage with a value of PBM_SETPOS which causes the progress bar to immediately update itself.

Comment: @ChrisDunaway I think that Jedi's first comment was more based on having a not-clear-understanding of how to interact with this control, rather than on an actual need to update the GUI. In any case, thanks for your comment; it will surely be helpful to Jedi or to anyone else reading all this. I just wanted to highlight that I, personally, don't think that certain things should be used systematically: everything when required :)